# C++ Build library and link it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fann

I'm trying to write a program that use FANN Library: http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/

I downloaded the source code, I opened the .sln project and compiled it. Now: what I have to do? I tried to create a new "console application project", I included the main header

```
#include "src\include\fann.h"
```

(I previously copied the src folder in my project folder)

I went on: Project->Properties->Linker->General and I pointed "directories library" to the "bin" folder in which VS compiled the .lib but I still have the error "unresolved external symbol" (the error, of course, is related to some functions that I'm calling in my code). I really don't know what to do, it's my first time I try to do something similar, I think I'm missing something important here...

Comment: What prevented you from reading the FANN documentation? As well as the library directory, you need to actually point to the library itself.

Comment: I read the FANN Documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your .lib into  Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.
You'll see combobox, in it 'edit...' and then you'll, get a window where you put the name of your library file. You have to have the library directory set as you did. You have to research what is the name of your library file.

In [this forum](http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?t=401), they are using 'libfann.lib' name.